# How to Sum JSON Array with Objects that Share a String Value

Tags: arrays, json, reduce

I am trying to consolidate similar JS Objects in an array based on a matching string value.

Starting with something like

```
let arr1 = [{
  str: "a",
  num: 10
}, {
  str: "a",
  num: 10
}, {
  str: "b",
  num: 5
}, {
  str: "b",
  num: 2
}, {
  str: "c",
  num: 4
}];
```

Dropping duplicate `str` entries and summing the indices

```
let arr2 = [{
  str: "a",
  num: 20
}, {
  str: "b",
  num: 7
}, {
  str: "c",
  num: 4
}];
```

Would I need to break `arr1` into `n` arrays, sum and then recombine, or is there a simpler approach with `map` and `reduce` that works well for nested properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a single loop and with a tmp array.

```
let arr1 = [{
  str: "a",
  num: 10
}, {
  str: "a",
  num: 10
}, {
  str: "b",
  num: 5
}, {
  str: "b",
  num: 2
}, {
  str: "c",
  num: 4
}];

var tarr = [];
var arr2 = [];

arr1.forEach( x => {
    var i = tarr.indexOf(x.str);
    if(i > -1){
        arr2[i].num += x.num;
    } else {
        tarr.push(x.str);
        arr2.push(x);
    }
});

console.log(arr2);
```